# Architecture of single method for ajax in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, angularjs, service

I'd like to understand how can i design single ajax-method for several controllers, which also can influence on user interface ('loading' animation, for example).

Idea is (without promises):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl',
    function myCtrl($scope, myFactory){
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.someStuff = myFactory.getStuff(params);
});

myApp.factory('myFactory', function(myService){
    return{
        getStuff: function(params){
            return myService.ajax(params);
        }
    }
});

myApp.service('myService', function($http) {
    this.ajax = function(params){
        // switch $scope.loading = true; 
        // make request
        // return $http result
        // switch $scope.loading = false; 
    };
});
```

As i know, i need use $scope for UI changes and ajax-method should be taken out to custom service. Services in Angularjs does not work with $scope and i have no idea how can i solve this problem.

I think, there must be a service with chain of promises. 
How can it be designed?

**Upd**: I hope, with the time the documentation will be more complete and clear. But community of angular users is already great. Thanks.

Comment: Services can work with $rootScope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project I have defined a service called `appState` which has (among other) methods: `showGlobalSpinner` and `hideGlobalSpinner` which modify a variable on the `$rootScope`.

Basically:

```
(…)
.factory('appState', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        showGlobalSpinner: function () {
            ++$rootScope.loadingInProgress;
        },
        hideGlobalSpinner: function () {
            if ($rootScope.loadingInProgress > 0) {
                --$rootScope.loadingInProgress
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

What I do next is I show spinners wherever I need them using `ng-show` directive:

`<div class="spinner" ng-show="loadingInProgress"></div>`

Before each AJAX I just call `AppState.showGlobalSpinner()` and after success/error I call `AppState.hideGlobalSpinner()`

Answer (score 0):

You could add this [method](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/services/httpRequestTracker.js) to any of your controllers:

```
.controller('HeaderCtrl',['$scope','httpRequestTracker', function($scope,httpRequestTracker) {
  $scope.hasPendingRequests = function () {
    return httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests();
  };
}]);


angular.module('services.httpRequestTracker', []);
angular.module('services.httpRequestTracker').factory('httpRequestTracker', ['$http', function($http){

  var httpRequestTracker = {};
  httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests = function() {
    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
  };

  return httpRequestTracker;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a more generic approach by using an HTTP interceptor, some events and a directive:

**Javascript**

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, $rootScope) {
  return function(promise) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('RequestStarted');

    var success = function(response) {    
      $rootScope.$broadcast('RequestFinished', true);
    };

    var error = function(response) {        
      $rootScope.$broadcast('RequestFinished', false);
      return $q.reject(response);
    };

    promise.then(success, error);
    return promise;
  }
})
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
})
.directive('loading', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-show="visible" ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.visible = false;

      $scope.$on('RequestStarted', function() {
        $scope.visible = true;
      });

      $scope.$on('RequestFinished', function() {
        $scope.visible = false;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
...
<loading><h1>Loading...</h1></loading>
...
```

You can see a working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QFBTINXTHzzsL44Go7re?p=preview).

By using an HTTP interceptor, you'll be able to track every HTTP request made by the `$http` service (`$resource` included) across you Angular application and show the load animation accordingly.